# Do Expectation Maximization always have to converge after a finite number of iterations if the implementation is correct?

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, unsupervised-learning, supervised-learning, expectation-maximization

I'm trying to understand how this could be possible, I know EM algorithm has the property to increase the likelihood for each step. However, this does not imply convergence. My question is, if the implementation IS proper and correct, EM will always converge in a case with a finite number of iterations?